# Serializing Array of Many Duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

So I have a series of arrays, each of which are 2500 long, and I need to serialize and store all them in very limited space.

Since I have many duplicates, I wanted to cut them down to something like below.

```
[0,0,0,0,2,7,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
// to
[0x4,2,7,3x2,0x9]
```

I wrote a couple one-liners (utilising Lodash' `_.repeat`) to convert to and from this pattern, however converting to doesn't seem to work in most/all cases.

```
let serialized = array.toString().replace(/((?:(\d)+,?)((?:\2+,?){2,}))/g, (m, p1, p2) => p2 + 'x' + m.replace(/,/g, '').length);

let parsed = serialized.replace(/(\d+)x(\d+),?/g, (z, p1, p2) => _.repeat(p1 + ',', +p2)).split(',');
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. It may be due to some of the numbers in the array. Eye-balling, the largest one is `4294967295`, however well over 90% is just `0`.

What am I missing in my RegEx that's preventing it from working correctly? Is there a simpler way that I'm too blind to see?

I'm fairly confident with converting it back from the serialized state, just need a hand getting it to the state.

Comment: It's an array of numbers. @gurvinder372

Comment: I would suggest avoiding Regex and just use plain JS to construct the second array from the first. `array.reduce` will be your friend.

Comment: As @JosephtheDreamer has suggested you should use `array.reduce` instead. [Sampe Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o636z1tg/)

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I don't see how I can use `reduce` for this, or perhaps I'm just stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight forward and simple serialization:

```js
let serialize = arr => {
    const elements = [];
    const counts = []
    let last = undefined;
    [0,0,0,0,2,7,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].forEach((el,i,arr)=>{
       if (el!==last) {
          elements.push(el);
          counts.push(1);
       } else {
          counts[counts.length-1]++;
       }
       last = el;
    })
    return elements.map((a,i)=>counts[i]>1?`${a}x${counts[i]}`:a).join(",");
};
console.log(serialize([0,0,0,0,2,7,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]));
```

**UPDATE**

Pure functional *serialize* one:

```js
let serialize = arr => arr
  .reduce((memo, element, i) => {
    if (element !== arr[i - 1]) {
      memo.push({count: 1, element});
    } else {
      memo[memo.length - 1].count++;
    }
    return memo;
  },[])
  .map(({count, element}) => count > 1 ? `${count}x${element}` : element)
  .join(",");
console.log(serialize([0,0,0,0,2,7,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]));
```

Pure functional *deserialize*:

```js
const deserialize = str => str
  .split(",")
  .map(c => c.split("x").reverse())
  .reduce((memo, [el, count = 1]) => memo.concat(Array(+count).fill(+el)), []);
console.log(deserialize("4x0,2,7,2x3,9x0"))
```

In order to avoid using `.reverse()` in this logic, I'd recommend to change serialization from `4x0` to `0x4`

Comment: Please note `<>` icon in editor. You can put your JS code and make it executable

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var arr = [0,0,0,0,2,7,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var finalArray = []; //array into which count of values will go

var currentValue = ""; //current value for comparison
var tmpArr = [];  //temporary array to hold values
arr.forEach( function( val, index ){
 if ( val != currentValue && currentValue !== "" )
 {
   finalArray.push( tmpArr.length + "x" + tmpArr[0] ); 
   tmpArr = [];
 }
 tmpArr.push(val);
 currentValue = val;
});
finalArray.push( tmpArr.length + "x" + tmpArr[0] );

console.log(finalArray);
```

Another version without temporary array

```js
var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var finalArray = []; //array into which count of values will go

var tmpCount = 0; //temporary variable to hold count
arr.forEach(function(val, index) {
  if ( (val != arr[ index - 1 ] && index !== 0 ) ) 
  {
    finalArray.push(tmpCount + "x" + arr[ index - 1 ] );
    tmpCount = 0;
  }
  tmpCount++;
  if ( index == arr.length - 1 )
  {
    finalArray.push(tmpCount + "x" + arr[ index - 1 ] );
  }
});

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use RegEx. Just use regular logic. I recommend `array.reduce` for this job.

```js
const arr1 = [0,0,0,0,2,7,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
const arr2 = ['0x4','2','7','3x2','0x9'];

const compact = arr => {
  const info = arr.reduce((c, v) =>{
    if(c.prevValue !== v){
      c.order.push(v);
      c.count[v] = 1;
      c.prevCount = 1;
      c.prevValue = v;
    } else {
      c.prevCount = c.prevCount + 1;
      c.count[v] = c.count[v] + 1;
    };
    return c;
  },{
    prevValue: null,
    prevCount: 0,
    count: {},
    order: []
  });
  
  return info.order.map(v => info.count[v] > 1 ? `${v}x${info.count[v]}` : `${v}`);
}

const expand = arr => {
  return arr.reduce((c, v) => {
    const split = v.split('x');
    const value = +split[0];
    const count = +split[1] || 1;
    Array.prototype.push.apply(c, Array(count).fill(value));
    return c;
  }, []);
}

console.log(compact(arr1));
console.log(expand(arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical reducing job. Here is your `compress` function done in just O(n) time..

```js
var arr      = [0,0,0,0,2,7,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    compress = a => a.reduce((r,e,i,a) => e === a[i-1] ? (r[r.length-1][1]++,r) : (r.push([e,1]) ,r),[]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(compress(arr)));
```

Answer (score -1):

since the motivation here is to reduce the size of the stored arrays, consider using something like [gzip-js](https://github.com/beatgammit/gzip-js) to compress your data.